# How do I post url $_GET['params'] when submitting form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I do this in my routes to check if $_GET exists

```
Route::get('/register', function(){
    if(isset($_GET['code'])){
        $referral = $_GET['code'];
    };

    return Response::view('user.register');
    }
);
```

Then in my view I do this

```
<div style='display:none'>
  <?php if (isset($referral)){ ?>
    {!! Form::hidden('referral', <?php $referral ?>) !!}
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

But when I submit the form it doesn't show up.

Also I had to use display none because {!! Form::hidden etc...!!} actually shows up on the ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relevant [doc on Laravel requests input](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input)

```
Route::get('/register', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
    if ($request->has('code')) {
        $referral = $request->input('code');
    }

    // I imagine you actually send $referral to the view here...
    return Response::view('user.register');
    }
);
```

In view:

```
@if (isset($referral))
    {!! Form::hidden('referral', $referral) !!}
@endif
```

When a form is submitted, its data is usually sent by POST, not GET. Using the `Request` methods abstracts that away and is much better than using the raw PHP array.

Comment: I submit the form to this route `Route::post('/register', 'UserController@create');` It still doesn't work with the changes you suggested.  I did var_dump(Input::all()) in my controller and it doesn't show up as one of the things submitted.

Comment: I also added `return Response::view('user.register', compact('referral'));` No luck =(

Comment: Also if you don't mind answering one more question for me, when a user starts browsing my site, how do i prevent the referral params from disappearing from the url?

Comment: You can add it to all the links you generate in your templates. Something like this `$url = route('routeName', ['referral' => $referral]);`